# How to safely add partition to boot drive of running server?

Tags: filesystems

I have a home server running Ubuntu 20.04 Server. It boots from a 240 GB SSD, in which the actual file system it boots from is only a 16 GB partition:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 223.57 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SV300S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5D341B88-AE4C-48F6-BB66-1C9861F16A8E

Device       Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdc1     2048  2203647  2201600   1G EFI System
/dev/sdc2  2203648 35758079 33554432  16G Linux filesystem
```

I want to format the remaining 223 GB of the drive as a partition that I can mount and put my actual data in. (The reason I have done this is because I want to be able to encrypt that partition to help protect against possible theft of the drive, and would rather have to SSH in and mount it with the encryption key each time the server reboots than deal with getting it to boot off an encrypted drive without assistance).

So, now I would like to add a partition to that disk, and `fdisk` helpfully warns:

```
This disk is currently in use - repartitioning is probably a bad idea.
It's recommended to umount all file systems, and swapoff all swap
partitions on this disk.
```

If this were some external drive I would simply `umount` it, but since it's the drive the system boots off of and is mounted over `/`, this isn't so simple (at least that's my understanding, I'm not a Linux expert).

I would much like to avoid getting the system into a situation where it doesn't boot without manual intervention. The machine lacks sufficient hardware to interface with a monitor whatsoever, so I essentially rely on it to boot up and automatically bootstrap into a state where I can SSH in at its static LAN IP. If it stops being able to do this it's really inconvenient, so I would like to avoid that.

Thanks!

Comment: unrelated to your question: If your machine has a [serial port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port), then I recommend setting it up so that you can login via the serial port.  i.e. by connecting to another nearby machine via a [Null Modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) cable and running a `getty` on the serial port device.  That will allow you to login and fix it even if the network interface has failed for some reason.  If your machine only has USB ports, it's also possible to do this with a USB serial port adaptor.

Comment: @cas oh thank you! I will look into that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't delete the root partition (`/dev/sdc2`), or shrink the partition without first shrinking the filesystem on it, modifying the partition table is safe.

The warning is there to discourage people who don't really know what they're doing from charging ahead and trashing their system without doing some research....so it has done its job :)

BTW, the same applies to any other partition in use, whether as a mounted fs or swap space or whatever else - don't delete that partition while it is in use. And don't shrink a fs partition without first shrinking the fs on it.  Note that some filesystems don't support being shrunk (some only support being grown), and some don't support either shrinking or growing.

Also BTW, as a general rule, it's usually safe to increase a partition's size as long as there's free space for it to expand into...that's generally how filesystems can be grown - first grow the partition, then use the appropriate filesystem-specific tool (e.g. `resize2fs` or `xfs_growfs`) to grow the filesystem.